# error: '' has not been declared

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to implement a linked list but get an error when compiling:

> intSLLst.cpp:38: error: ‘intSLList’ has not been declared

intSLList looks like it's been declared to me though so I'm really confused.

intSLLst.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "intSLLst.h"


int intSLList::deleteFromHead(){
}

int main(){

}
```

intSLLst.h

```
#ifndef INT_LINKED_LIST
#define INT_LINKED_LIST
#include <cstddef>

class IntSLLNode{
  int info;
  IntSLLNode *next;

  IntSLLNode(int el, IntSLLNode *ptr = NULL){
    info = el; next = ptr;
  }

};

class IntSLList{
 public:
  IntSLList(){
    head = tail = NULL;
  }

  ~IntSLList();

  int isEmpty();
  bool isInList(int) const;

  void addToHead(int);
  void addToTail(int);

  int deleteFromHead();
  int deleteFromTail();
  void deleteNode(int);

 private:
  IntSLLNode *head, *tail;

};

#endif
```

Comment: Consider using `std::list<int>`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're using a lower case i

```
int intSLList::deleteFromHead(){
}
```

should be

```
int IntSLList::deleteFromHead(){
}
```

Names in c++ are always case sensitive.

Answer (score 12):

`intSLList` isn't the same as `IntSLList`. This isn't Pascal. C++ is case sensitive.